# SQL error 42X01 in derby

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, derby

I get this error:

> ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "CURRENT_TIME" at line 1,
>   column 195. Issue the 'help' command for general information on IJ
>   command syntax. Any unrecognized commands are treated as potential SQL
>   commands and executed directly.
>   Consult your DBMS server reference
>   documentation for details of the SQL syntax supported by your server.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER USUARIOSTRIGGER AFTER UPDATE ON USUARIOS REFERENCING OLD AS           
UPDATEDROW FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL INSERT INTO USUARIOSLOGS VALUES         
(UPDATEDROW.NOMBRE,UPDATEDROW.APELLIDO,                                                             
UPDATEDROW.CURRENT_TIME,UPDATEDROW.CURRENT_DATE,'INSERTED FROM   
USUARIOSTRIGGER');
```

Answer (score 1):

The names `CURRENT_TIME` and `CURRENT_DATE` are [reserved words](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html) for system functions, and can't be used as column names without quoting them.

However in the code shown it looks like you actually want to get the current time and current date, so you should remove the row reference.

So use:

```
CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE
```

Instead of

```
UPDATEDROW.CURRENT_TIME,UPDATEDROW.CURRENT_DATE
```